# ComponentDidMount unusual behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I was going through react docs where it showed implementation of clock timer.
when the component has mounted, the componentDidMount method is called and hence the setInterval inside it is executed, so after 1 second that state changes and the Clock component gets re-rendered. I am fine until this point, but how the senInterval function is invoked again? because componentDidMount gets called only once, so how is state getting set after ever second, could come one please explain what is happening here.

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds)

That is what setInterval is doing. It can be used to repeat some task in certain interval. If you want to do it only once, use setTimeout() instead.

[setInterval ReadMore](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)
[setTimeout ReadMore](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Answer (score 0):

setInterval is a function that keeps calling itself at intervals, in this case, 1 second. what componentDidMount does is to execute the code inside of it once after the component has mounted.

So in this case, componentDidMount called the setInterval once and the setInterval kept calling itself every 1 second till you clear it in componentWillUnmount.